# Trying to call function which accepts multiple alternate classes and getting Error CS0308

Tags: c#, interface

I'm trying to create a call to a C# .NET 7 function which I've created which will accept a number of different classes all using the same interface.

I created the following interface class:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2.Models;

public interface CommonInterfaces<T> where T : class
{
    public List<T> items { get; set; }
}

public interface CommonInterface
{
    DateTime? createdOn { get; set; }
    DateTime? modifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

I then created the class based on the interface:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2.Models;

public class Agents : CommonInterfaces<Agent>
{
    public List<Agent> items { get; set; }
}

public partial class Agent : CommonInterface
{
    public DateTime? createdOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? modifiedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? lastModified { get; set; }

    public string? dataDescription { get; set; }
    public bool? isDeleted { get; set; }
    public string? primaryKey { get; set; }
}
```

I created a function:

```
static async Task ProcessAgentSync<S, T>() 
    where S : CommonInterface where T : CommonInterfaces<CommonInterface>, new()
{
    T data = new T();
}
```

When I try calling `ProcessAgentSync`:

```
await ProcessAgentSync<Agent, Agents<Agent>>();
```

I get the error:

> The non-generic type 'Agents' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: What is your question? The error message is clear, you probably want either `await ProcessAgentSync<Agent, Agents>();` or add a generic type parameter for `Agents`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is fairly clear. `Agents` is not a generic class, it only inherits from an generic interface. So `Agents<Agent>` is not a valid type.

So lets change it to `ProcessAgentSync<Agent, Agents>`. But this will still not work. `Agents` is a `CommonInterfaces<Agent>`, but is not a `CommonInterfaces<CommonInterface>`.

This may be a [covariance or contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) problem, but the example does not do anything meaningful, so it difficult to provide recommendations.

Perhaps you should change your common interface to:

```
public interface CommonInterfaces<out T> where T : class
{
    public IReadOnlyList<T> Items { get; }
}
```

Or

```
public interface CommonInterfaces
{
    public List<CommonInterface> items { get; set; }
}
```

Either *could* solve your problem, but it is difficult to tell without understanding what problem you are trying to solve. I would in general caution against trying to write overly generic code. It is fairly easy to end up with a very complicated code that is difficult to work with.